# Docker Toolbox: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Maximum number of retries (5) exceeded

Tags: windows-7, docker

I'm on Windows 7, VirtualBox 5.0.4, Docker toolbox 1.9.0. When I run the quickstart I get:

```
Creating Machine default...
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Maximum number of retries (5) exceeded
Looks like something went wrong... Press any key to continue...
```

But I do get a running 'default' VM when I open VirtualBox and have a look. In my VBox.log I see (full file is [here](http://pastebin.com/wJwJ9NDP)):

```
00:00:00.696246 HM: HMR3Init: VT-x w/ nested paging and unrestricted guest execution hw support
```

So maybe VT-X support is ok for me. Right at the end of the logfile I see somthing ominous about D-Bus not being installed:

```
00:00:46.950561 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:10.018836 vminfo   Error: Unable to connect to system D-Bus (3/3): D-Bus not installed
```

The D-Bus issue has been reported here https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/214 When I run the quickstart again directly after this, I get an error message about getting an IP address:

```
Machine default already exists in VirtualBox.
Setting environment variables for machine default...
Error running connection boilerplate: Error getting driver URL: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show dev eth1
err     : exit status 255
output  :


                    ##         .
              ## ## ##        ==
           ## ## ## ## ##    ===
       /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
  ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
       \______ o           __/
         \    \         __/
          \____\_______/

Error getting IP address: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show dev eth1
err     : exit status 255
output  :
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com
NOTE: When using interactive commands, prepend winpty. Examples: 'winpty     docker run -it ...', 'winpty docker exec -it ...'.
```

And if I run a command, I get another message relating to connecting:

```
$ winpty docker run hello-world
An error occurred trying to connect: Post     http://localhost:2375/v1.21/containers
/create: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: ConnectEx tcp: No connection could be made     because the target machine actively refused it.
```

At this point I went to https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds and got VirtualBox 5.0.9, and then uninstalled Docker Toolboox, deleted the default VM and the .docker directory, and reinstalled the Toolbox, and re-run it, and got the same problem:

```
Creating Machine default...
Creating CA: C:\Users\marwick\.docker\machine\certs\ca.pem
Creating client certificate: C:\Users\marwick\.docker\machine\certs\cert.pem
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Maximum number of retries (5) exceeded
Looks like something went wrong... Press any key to continue...
```

The logfile for this attempt is here: http://pastebin.com/9VjD9t6P

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 12):

Had same problem (running docker commands gives error message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it).
There are problems with permissions (likely the target machine was created under a different user account).

This worked for me:
Open Oracle VM VirtualBox and right-click the machine named 'default'. If it is running, select "Close -> Power off".  Then select "Remove ..." and hit "Delete all files" button.

close Oracle VM VirtualBox and run Docker_Quickstart again. It will create a new default VM with no permission problems.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well.

Comment: I'm glad it's working for others, but I've done this several times, and deleting the dotfiles associated with the VM, and there's no improvement.

Comment: @Ben you ought to delete files from within virtualbox UI (delete all files)

Answer (score 0):

Ben, Maybe u use the ghost system， then ur uxtheme.dll was cracked, leading to ur VM start failure.
Use the original uxtheme.dll to replace the c:\windows\system32\uxtheme.dll, then it will create a new default VM with no permission problems.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'ghost system'? I don't understand :$

Comment: @Ben I think he means that your os was cloned from another hard disk.